# It is possible to match subexpression only in tcl regexp?

Tags: regex, tcl

$report contains the following text:

```
// Command : generate report
Report 123
------------------------------
status        Names
------------------------------
Flat     :    Module1
Flat     :    Module2 
------------------------------
Total Flattened = 2
```

I want to extract the module names only.  There is an unknown number of modules.  It would be really nice if I could do something like this:

```
set modules [regexp -all -inline {Flat\s+:\s+(\S+)} $report]
```

but that puts a bunch of extra junk in $modules that I don't care about.  Am I missing something?  I know there are ways of getting around this.  It just seems strange that there doesn't seem to be a way to turn off matching the full expression.  Especially since there is syntax for turning off subexpression matching (?:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to not get the full match strings.

```
lmap {full capture} $modules {set capture}
```

Picks out the captured strings for you.

```
# for Tcl 8.5 and earlier
set res [list]
foreach {full capture} $modules {lappend res $capture}
```

You get all that stuff because it could be relevant, and if not it's very easy to pick out the bits you do want.

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

[Getting `lmap` for Tcl 8.5 and earlier](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570)

Comment: Hmm... lmap is a 8.6 feature.  I'm using TCL version 8.5 so I wouldn't be able to do that anyway.

Comment: I can't update the TCL version. I am running my script from withinside a 3rd party tool compiled with tcl 8.5.

Comment: @NathanPeterson: I can't remember why I made that rather unhelpful comment, but I think I meant that you should take a look at the "Getting lmap for Tcl 8.5 and earlier" link. On that page is a pure-Tcl version of lmap that you can add to your code.